# XSLT value-of with multiple children of different types

Tags: xslt, xpath, value-of

why do I get with that data:

```
<A>
  <B>block 1</B>
  <B>block 2</B>
  <C>
    no
  </C>
  <B>block 3</B>
</A>
```

and this transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method= "html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="A/B">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/> <br/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the following output:

```
block 1
block 2
no block 3
```

I'd expect it to be:

```
block 1
block 2
block 3
```

So: Why does the C block getting included?

//EDIT
Tested with the thing here:
http://www.ladimolnar.com/JavaScriptTools/XSLTransform.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the [Default Template Rules](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/xmlnut/ch08_07.htm).

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()|@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

The XSL processor examines each node in turn, looking for a matching template.  If it doesn't find one, it uses the default template, which just outputs the text.  In your case the following happens ("no match" means no match in *your* stylesheet):

```
/A         no match, apply-templates (default element template)
/A/B       match, output text
/A/B       match, output text
/A/C       no match, apply-templates
/A/C/text  no match, output text (default text template)
/A/B       match, output text
```

To skip the path `/A/C` just add an empty template

```
<xsl:template match="A/C"/>
```

This will match the unwanted element and suppress output.

Comment: Thanks and how can I get the desired output then if you allow me this followup?